# mutiple button in HTML in struts framework

Tags: struts

I have five buttons in my HTML code each doing differnt task . I have written one form bean and five different action classes since on click of submit button all five buttons do completely different business operation altoghether.

Am I doing it right . If so how to capture this scenarion in my struts.xml

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I like to have 1 Action class for every action a user can take. So if they are executing different business logic, then I think you are right to have just 5 different Action classes.

1 form bean also probably makes sense, if all the buttons correspond to the same form.

As far as how to capture this in the struts.xml, I don't think you need to do anything special. Just configure the 5 actions as you would normally, and specify 5 different actions, all using the same form bean.

```
<!--This example is not tested, it is just to give you an idea-->
<form-beans>
    <form-bean
        name="form1"
        type="app.Form1"/>
</form-beans>
<action-mappings>
    <action
        path="/Action1"
        type="app.Action1"
        name="form1"
        input="/pages/input.jsp">
        <forward
            name="success"
            path="/pages/success.jsp"/>
        <forward
            name="failure"
            path="/pages/input.jsp"/>
    </action>
    <action
        path="/Action2"
        type="app.Action2"
        name="form1"
        input="/pages/input.jsp">
        <forward
            name="success"
            path="/pages/success.jsp"/>
        <forward
            name="failure"
            path="/pages/input.jsp"/>
    </action>
    <action
        path="/Action3"
        type="app.Action3"
        name="form1"
        input="/pages/input.jsp">
        <forward
            name="success"
            path="/pages/success.jsp"/>
        <forward
            name="failure"
            path="/pages/input.jsp"/>
    </action>
    <action
        path="/Action4"
        type="app.Action4"
        name="form1"
        input="/pages/input.jsp">
        <forward
            name="success"
            path="/pages/success.jsp"/>
        <forward
            name="failure"
            path="/pages/input.jsp"/>
    </action>
    <action
        path="/Action5"
        type="app.Action5"
        name="form1"
        input="/pages/input.jsp">
        <forward
            name="success"
            path="/pages/success.jsp"/>
        <forward
            name="failure"
            path="/pages/input.jsp"/>
    </action>
</action-mappings>
```